# Rails Query JOIN with WHERE NOT doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to figure out how come this query doesn't work:

```
@items = Item.joins(:assignments).where.not(assignments: {shop_id: some_id})
```

I want to get all items that do not have an assignment association with some shop_id.

It's weird that it doesn't work considering this query will work (only show items with assignment association some shop_id):

```
@items = Item.joins(:assignments).where(assignments: {shop_id: some_id})
```

Comment: Are you getting some error while using `not`? or just getting empty result?

Comment: Is there any error? What's your Rails version?

Comment: @MoamenNaanou I am getting a result with all items

Comment: @SebastianPalma No error, getting all items in return. Rails 5.1.5

Comment: What are the sql queries both versions return?

Comment: give it a try to this flyer... `Item.joins(:assignments).where("assignments.shop_id = ?", some_id)`

Comment: @SikandarTariq your query works, but it is not what i am looking for. I am looking for all items where assignment.shop_id IS NOT some_id

Comment: @SebastianPalma SELECT  "items"."id", "items"."created_at", "items"."updated_at", "items"."warehouse_stock", "items"."price_cents", "items"."price_currency" FROM "items" INNER JOIN "assignments" ON "assignments"."item_id" = "items"."id" WHERE ("assignments"."shop_id" != $1) LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3  [["shop_id", 4], ["LIMIT", 20], ["OFFSET", 0]]

Comment: oo yes, try with where.not

Comment: @SikandarTariq the reason for the post is because where.not did not give me the result i wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to learn how SQL [`JOIN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) [works](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

You get all `Item` just because `Assignment`s with "good" `shop_id` exist also. So, Rails does it right.

Query you need should looks like:

```
Item.where.not(
  id: Assignment.where(shop_id: some_id).select(:item_id)
)
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to work. I'm still getting items where they have an assignment with shop_id some_id

Comment: Please provide exact result of `Assignment.where(shop_id: some_id).pluck(:item_id)`